# Firefox for Android and HTML5 canvas transparency bug

Tags: android, html, firefox, html5-canvas

Consider this simple webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas width="100" height="100" id="the-canvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Basically, it contains only one `<canvas/>` element that has semi-transparent blue background. The expected behavior is to have it rendered in light blue color, since the background of the web page is white.

It renders fine on the desktop machine.

On Android it renders fine as well, except for Firefox, where it acts like the page underneath canvas was actually.. black. **The strangest thing** is that it acts like it **only** if there is any part of Firefox's interface visible on the screen!

Examples below.

Good behavior - color is light blue. No parts of Firefox's interface are visible.
[image: Good behavior]

---

Wrong behavior - the resulting color suddenly gets way too dark. Note that Firefox's interface comes into view as I sweep my screen to see the address bar.

### [image: Wrong behavior]

Here's another example; this time I try to render corny snow animation to celebrate incoming Christmas. To do that, I render small opaque circles on transparent canvas. Version on the left - Firefox interface visible, circles have ugly anti-aliasing problems; version on the right - the same page after scrolling a bit down, circles are rendered correctly.

[image: Another example]

I tried to use various [blending features](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/01/28/blending-features-in-canvas/) to get around this, but without success.

Comment: Did you try to explicitely set the CSS style `body: { background-color:#ffffff; }`?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem. Setting it to other colors, like `#f00`, produces the same behavior.

Comment: what happens when you position the canvas over a non-transparent `<div>`? Is setting the background-color of the canvas itself an option?

Comment: I'd be happy if it was an option, but transparency is crucial in my use case (see snowflakes example - they're supposed to cover the webpage). Setting background color to underlying `<div>` isn't much different from setting background to `<body>` and checking it shows that it doesn't work as well. Of course I can resort to switching from canvas to something else, but it'd be nice to have this code working, since it already works everywhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Just wondering is this is a "web safe" colour issue!